# Could not find androidx.navigation:safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha01

Tags: android, gradle, android-architecture-navigation

I want to use Navigation Architecture Components.

But I got a problem with importing [safeargs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#Safe-args)

Sync message:

> Could not find androidx.navigation:safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha01. 
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/safe-args-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-alpha01/safe-args-gradle-plugin-1.0.0-alpha01.pom
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/safe-args-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-alpha01/safe-args-gradle-plugin-1.0.0-alpha01.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/navigation/safe-args-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-alpha01/safe-args-gradle-plugin-1.0.0-alpha01.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/navigation/safe-args-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-alpha01/safe-args-gradle-plugin-1.0.0-alpha01.jar
>   Required by:
>   project :

I followed [Adding Components to your Project](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components) but does not solved my problem.

Project: build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha01"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module: build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mangoslab.navigation"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha01"

    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:${nav_version}" // use -ktx for Kotlin
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:${nav_version}" // use -ktx for Kotlin

    // optional - Test helpers
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-testing:${nav_version}" // use -ktx for Kotlin
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, it’s a bug on their side. Issue is tracked here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79454383

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try to add

```
classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha01"
```

instead of

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha01"
```

Comment: for the ref https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components

Answer (score 9):

Now you can use the following classpath in order to use safe-args with AndroidX

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0-alpha02"
```

For more details you can check [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#safeargs)

Answer (score 4):

I simply followed the androidx navigation release documentation
[Jetpack libraries Navigation Framework](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation)

In app level build.gradle file inside the dependencies block I've added

```
def nav_version = "2.1.0"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:$nav_version"
```

also you need to add the following at the top of the file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

Within the project top level build.gradle file include the following classpath

```
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0"
```

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer didn't work for me. But when I used `alpha 5` it worked

Project `build.gradle`:

```
classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha05"
```

Answer (score 2):

all of the above did not work for me. I only needed to put
 `apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"` after
 `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`

Comment: Thanks, this was the last change needed for me. Unless otherwise needed I always alphabetize so this bit me (androidx before kotlin).

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by replacing

```
classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$version_navigation"
```

in project level build where version_navigation = "2.1.0"  with

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$version_navigation"
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps to resolve your problem

**1.** **build.gradle** (*Module-level* )

**Add this in top of the file**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
}
```

Add below dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
```

**2.** **build.gradle** (*Project-level*)

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31'
    classpath 'androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

dont use

```
classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:..."
```

but

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:.."
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add this plugin :

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

at the bottom and worked perfectly.