# Plugin with id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' not found

Tags: android-studio, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

When I try to add Safe Args (Android Navigation) to my app's as following

( using this guide : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-pass-data ) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {...
```

I receive this error :

> **Plugin with id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' not found.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284338/could-not-find-androidx-navigationsafe-args-gradle-plugin1-0-0-alpha01

Comment: [Declaring Dependencies](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#declaring_dependencies)  | 
[SafeArgs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#safe_args)

Comment: For new gradle https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805989/8663316

Answer (score 141, accepted):

##### In Android Studio bellow bumblebee

To add `androidx.navigation.safeargs`plugin follow below step's

1. `classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.2-alpha09"`
   (latest)
   Add above to your Project Gradel file inside **dependency block**
2. Then add `apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'` to your app/Module gradle file

##### In Android Studio bumblebee+

```
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.4.2' apply false
```

Comment: Worth adding this link as well. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#safe_args in case the dependency version changes later.

Comment: It's working when I add it to my project gradle but not Module gradle. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Does not work. Adding, removing - same output.

Comment: I added both to the project Gradle file. The second step must be in the app gradle file.

Answer (score 69):

You can use dependencies as below in Project level bulild.gradle in Android Studio bumblebee

```
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.4.2' apply false
```

Comment: id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.7.7' apply false

Answer (score 27):

Just add this line in your build.gradle project level :

```
 classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.2.0-rc02"
```

Answer (score 18):

In newer version of Android Studio 3.2+, below dependency need to add in both ***build.gradle*** file

**Project-Level** *build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5'
}
```

**App-Level** *build.gradle*

```
plugins {
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your information. Clear answer, really helpful.

Comment: This done the job for me. Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 2.

Answer (score 13):

Add this line in **Project-level** build gradle

```
 id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.4.2' apply false
```

Add this in **App-level** build gradle

```
plugins {
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' 
}
```

Answer (score 12):

It appears because you are declaring it in the wrong build.gradle file. You have to place it in the build.gradle that looks like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.1.0"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}
```

This link explain how it is added https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#safe_args

Comment: I have no file that looks like this :/ In my kotlin project (migrated from java) there is no "buildscript". They should make some tools to make these gradle files. Every my project is diffrent, because everything is diffrent after some time.

Comment: @Kamil that's weird, try to create a new project and compare it to your current one. That's how you may match which is which

Answer (score 12):

Add

`classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0-alpha05"`

In your project-level dependencies

For eg :

```
dependencies {
       classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0-alpha05"

}
```

Don't forget to add the latest version

Answer (score 5):

as per this https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation

Add above to your Project Gradel file inside dependency block

```
`classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.2.1`
```

then add 
    `apply plugin: androidx.navigation.safeargs`
to your app/Module gradle file

Answer (score 2):

I had to add it to the top level build.gradle, not sure if you've just added it to your app level build.gradle instead

Answer (score 1):

FYI: I had to add it in this manner in order for it to work in Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1:

Gradle Scripts > build.gradle (Project: YourProject)

```
plugins {
id blah
.
.
.
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.4.2' apply false
```

}

And also here:

Gradle Scripts > build.gradle (Module: YourProject.app)

```
dependencies {
implementation blah
.
.
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.6.0-alpha02'
testImplementation blah
androidTestImplementation blah
```

}

Comment: Well, it turns out that if you add safe args to your project in this manner, you get a bunch of duplicate class errors. So in reality, because safe-args must be in some other package, just adding the plugin like this:

 `id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.5.2' apply false` 

worked or me. I just removed the implementation code.

Comment: Ok, well this answer only works to allow a sync and build. However, when you move to the next step of the tutorial at [Build Your First Android App](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app#8) and apply your navigation between the FirstFragment and the SecondFragment you get a FirstFragmentDirections class not found error. After much searching and trying different fixes this answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70445647/666567) is what finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

For me, adding this in the build.gradle (Project) worked.

```
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.4.2' apply false
```

Answer (score 1):

Go at the project level build gradle.kts
then paste this

`id ("androidx.navigation.safeargs") version "2.4.2" apply false`

Now switch back to app level gradle.kts
paste this within plugins

`id ("androidx.navigation.safeargs")`

Answer (score -1):

I hope this may help others. I followed the directions at developer.android.com and all the instructions here.  None of them solved the issue for me.
Mine was a simple order of operation in my modules build.gradle file.
I had:
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
listed as the first line in my plugins block.
moving to the end of the block solved my issue