# How to add classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version" in the new Gradle plugin?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

In the new project Gradle plugin has a lot of changes and I can't add classpath for safe args. How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add this above plugins in your top level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.2")
    }
}
```

And in App level build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
}
```