# Android Studio error "Could not find android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5"

Tags: android, android-studio

When I build my Android Studio app, I got an error "Could not find android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5". But I have implemented "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5". The error appeared after updating gradle.
Here is whole error:
[image]

Comment: Have you added `apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'` at the top of your build gradle?

Comment: Yes, but nothing changed

Comment: Did you add the `"androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"` plugin dependency in your project `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Yes, but it also didn't change anything

Comment: check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284338/could-not-find-androidx-navigationsafe-args-gradle-plugin1-0-0-alpha01

Comment: None of the answers didn't work for me.

Comment: As stated earlier down grade dependency to 4.1.3 ic could be found under project level gradle file dependencies class path

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by downgrading the gradle plugin to 4.1.3

in build.graddle project level:

From this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
}
```

to this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
}
```

Comment: I need to use jetpack compose, so the minimum version should be 4.2.2. and there isn't any solution for that!!!

Answer (score 3):

Try using Android Jetpack stuff.

Replace:

```
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5"
```

with

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5"
```

in the module-level (app) build.gradle file.